# Glob string stored in a variable is not expanded when used in a command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to work on a set of files with various extensions but I'm not that experienced with the inner workings of bash... this is what I' trying to accomplished (stripped down):

```
DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN="*.{yaml,md}";
pandoc -s -f markdown -o combined.html $DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN;
```

results in

```
pandoc: *.{yaml,md}: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Whereas when I do it directly

```
pandoc -s -f markdown -o combined.html *.{yaml,md};
```

it works perfectly.

The value of `$DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN` is really generated by command line arguments and not hard coded, otherwise the direct approach in the example above would be good enough already.

**as requested, here's a fully self contained example**

put the below code into a test.sh script within an empty directory

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup
touch 0001.md
touch 0002.md
touch metadata.yaml

# actual functionality under test
DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN="yaml,md";

shopt -s nullglob;
DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILES=( *.{$DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN} );

echo "required logic below:";
echo "${DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILES[@]}";

echo;
echo "working solution with hardcoding:";
DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILES=( *.{yaml,md} );
echo "${DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILES[@]}";

# tear down
rm *.{yaml,md};
```

Comment: I would expect to see the first behaviour if no files matched the pattern (perhaps you're in the wrong directory?), or if you had quotes around `"$DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN"`.

Comment: I have a feeling that you have over-stripped down your example. We need additional information to help you solve this problem.

Comment: @TomFenech fair point, I've added a self contained script in the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line, you are trying to double-expand (first `$DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN`, then the resulting pattern):

```
DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILES=( *.{$DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN} );
```

You can't do that directly.

If you trust that `$DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN` isn't going to contain malicious input, then you can achieve what you want using `eval`:

```
eval DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILES=( *.{$DOCUMENT_SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN} )
```

But instead, you could (**should**) probably try to do this in a different way, like add the files you want to an array, instead of trying to dynamically create a brace expansion in your code:

```
# prevent literal globs being added to the array when no files match
shopt -s nullglob 

source_files=()
if <whatever condition to add markdown files>; then
    source_files+=( *.md )
fi

if <whatever condition to add yaml files>; then
    source_files+=( *.yaml )
fi
```

Comment: I understand. Is there an option without use of eval though?

Comment: Yeah, it's there in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to add a glob string in a variable. Use an array and do quoted array expansion. The `nullglob` is to ensure the *literal* glob string is not passed to the array but only the expanded list if available

```
shopt -s nullglob
document_source_file_pattern=( *.{yaml,md} )
```

and pass the array as

```
pandoc -s -f markdown -o combined.html "${document_source_file_pattern[@]}"
```

as one more level of safe-way you could do below, which runs your `pandoc` command only the array is non-zero.

```
(( "${#document_source_file_pattern[@]}" )) &&
    pandoc -s -f markdown -o combined.html "${document_source_file_pattern[@]}"
```

Comment: Good advice, but the OP's code should work for well-behaved file names.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but the extension literals will be in a variable of their own and this does seem to throw this off. What I'm trying to say is that I can't place "yaml,md" into the code as a literal, it'll be a variable.

Comment: added a self contained example to the OP for more clarity

Comment: @DominiqueStender: Yes, I think Tom's answer provides insight more. I composed the answer _based_ on the static thought of fixed extension literals and not dynamic.